# Excel If statement to capture any date in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to capture a cell and put it on another sheet only when it's a date.  Is there a way where I can say that =IF('Master Intake Tracker'!K7="Any Date",'Master Intake Tracker'!I7,"")........any way to do this?  And also not capture if cell is unanswered? so if the cell is blank it won't capture and sent to another sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use the following user-defined function (which simply makes a VBA function available on the spreadsheet:

```
Function IsADate(aCell As Range) As Boolean

  If IsDate(aCell.Value) Then
    IsADate = TRUE
  Else
    IsADate = FALSE
  End If

End Function
```

This function will return TRUE if a cell has a regular date-formatted Excel value or if it has a string that specifies a date (such as "November 3, 2012").

Usage would be simple:

```
=IF(ISADATE('Master Intake Tracker'!K7),'Master Intake Tracker'!I7,"")
```

Comment: Is that any different from `=IF(LEFT(CELL("format", K7), 1) = "D", …, "")`?

Comment: +1 Your formula works for a date value (which is most likely what nixda wants to check!), but not for a string representation of a date.

Comment: @Scott - I note that CELL("format", K7) would return D9 if K7 is a time entry like `13:21`

Comment: So you’re answering nixda’s answer rather than user192213’s question?  It’s sure easier that way; as I said in my post, I find the OP to be somewhat vague and ambiguous.  Thanks for the crash course on `IsDate`.

Comment: Guess I've gotten confused on who's asking the question. You're wecome.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are simply formatted numbers in Excel - difficult to explicitly check for a date, but you can probably just do this:

`=IF('Master Intake Tracker'!K7>0,'Master Intake Tracker'!I7,"")`

that follows the logic of the formula in your question - if you want to return the date itself then change to:

`=IF('Master Intake Tracker'!K7>0,'Master Intake Tracker'!K7,"")`

Comment: Didn't capture the cell.

Comment: following the logic of the formula in your post my suggested formula looks at K7 and if that contains a number > 0 (a date) then the formula will return the value from I7, otherwise a blank - is it supposed to be I7 or the date itself? I edited my answer.....

Comment: @barry: I note that `K7>0` would evaluate to TRUE if K7 is a time entry like `13:21`.  :)

Comment: @Scott - touché!

Answer (score 1):

Use `=DateValue` and let Excel decide if your input is a valid date.

Assuming your test cell is A1, you can use this formula:
`=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"MM/DD/YYYY"))),"no its not!","its a date!")`

[image]

Customized to your example:
`=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT('Master Intake Tracker'!K7,"MM/DD/YYYY"))),"",'Master Intake Tracker'!K7)`

Comment: .....but that's actually the wrong way round - DATEVALUE converts a text representation of a date to a true date - if A1 contains a true date DATEVALUE(A1) returns an error.....

Comment: Fixed. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague and ambiguous. If you mean “[is it] a date, *stored as a date (in Excel’s numerical representation of dates)*?”, then

```
=IF(AND(K7<=NOW(), K7>=(TODAY()-365)), …, "")
```

might be a good place to start.